# What is the cheapest way to connect to Nasdaq for market data and trading *electronically*?

Tags: market-data, nasdaq

I would like to connect to Nasdaq to execute some simple automated strategies. I am **NOT** a big bank or hedge fund, so paying a high monthly fee is impractical. Is there a way for a small startup or individual to get connectivity to the Nasdaq markets without having to pay a high monthly fee?

Please don't worry about latencies as I understand that the less I pay the more will be the latency. Our strategies will not be latency-sensitive.

Comment: Check http://www.nasdaqomx.com/transactions/technicalinformation/connectivity

Answer (score 1):

First consider if you really need to be connected to just the Nasdaq or should you be using a broker that can connect you to all exchanges.  Almost certainly the answer is the later.

If that is the case then [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/home.php) is probably the way you want to go.  I've setup several [CTAs](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cta.asp) to get started with IB and its probably the best 3rd party to get setup with when you don't have the assets to get a big Sell side firm to look at you.

Once you are huge then you can spend to setup a  full hedge fund structure and prime with one of the typical sell side firms:)